# Benefits and Deployment Options of Node.JS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, blocking, nonblocking

I've never used node.js and understand that it's used for non-blocking realtime sites.  I had a couple of questions though:

1. Is node.js okay to use with PHP (or should I use Python)?
2. What are some good hosting places to deploy this (heroku?)?
3. Is there anyplace I can just download it from with customizing it, or do I have to write a node.js server myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Actual Node.js code is always written in JavaScript (or something that ends up as JavaScript, like CoffeeScript or ClojureScript). But you can use it in conjunction with an app written in any language. In a nutshell, you'll want to have the two apps talk to each other either through HTTP or an intermediary datastore or message queue like Redis or ØMQ (depending on, for example, how tightly coupled you need the two apps' actions to be).
2. Heroku would work fine, as would JoyentCloud or a custom server setup. Joyent is the main commercial backer of Node.js, but they're even more expensive than Heroku. Just like with any other kind of app, you and your pocketbook have to decide what server type fits your needs best.
3. You can download Node.js from nodejs.org, and there are [packages for many Linux distros](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager). For any node app, you do kind of have to "write a server," but that's because Node apps are HTTP servers. Aside from all the app logic, it's basically as simple as `server.listen(8080)`.